# Navagate to a certain cell in google sheets with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

Is it possible to get the display data from a cell and navigate to the cell that it displays?
Ex:

`Sheet Eric`

`A   B   C   D   E`

`1`  `D4`

`2`

`3`

`4`

It would get the text from the cell `B1` and go to the cell it displays(In this case `D4`)? I have tried:

```
function myFunction()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eric");
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("D50");
}
```

I have also recently asked a question on this but due to my poor English skills not many people understood what I meant. I want to change the last line, the `setActiveSelection("D50");` part and edit it so that it can get text from cell `B1` and go to the cell it displays. This part was a problem with my past question. It would for some reason read the formula, which I guess was a flop. If you could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To get a valaue of a cell use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Sample modification of your code:

```js
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eric");
  var activeCellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection(activeCellValue);
}
```

- This will retrieve the value of the cell that is active at the moment you run the script
- If the cell content is a valid A1-notation of a cell, the code will highlight the corresponding cell